# Flaticon icons display locally but not on live site?

Tags: icons

Urggh. This is all the more confusing because the CSS and file references must be right - it's working offline - so why wouldn't it work on the live site?

Here's the local view.  The first three icons - the Window, Door and Conservatory - are Flaticon icons:

[image: Page in local view]

Here's the same page on the live site (www.bairdswindows.co.uk):

[image: Page in live view]

This is my flaticon.css file which is located in my 'css' directory:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Flaticon";
src: url("../icons/flaticon.eot");
src: url("../icons/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("../icons/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
url("../icons/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("../icons/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
font-family: Flaticon;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.flaticon-bill:before {
content: "\e000";
}
.flaticon-calculator18:before {
content: "\e001";
}
.flaticon-doorway:before {
content: "\e002";
}
.flaticon-house112:before {
content: "\e003";
}
.flaticon-open203:before {
content: "\e004";
}
.flaticon-opened33:before {
content: "\e005";
}
.flaticon-window-frame:before {
content: "\e006";
}
```

The icons, on the live site, are appearing as small boxes with what looks like their e0001 etc title so the browser is seeing them, on the live site, it just isn't interpreting them and/or converting them to the icons.

Considering that it works locally, it has me completely stumped and I haven't been able to get a response from Flaticon support as of yet.  Hope someone can point out the obvious problem.

Thank you.
NJ

Comment: Does your folder structure on the server match what you have locally? For example, if you have your css in "resources/css" and fonts in "resources/icons" locally, does your css and font files share the same parent folder on the server?

Comment: Yes, they're identical.  Locally I'm testing using http://localhost/ so the directory structure is exactly the same. The browser just isn't rendering the icons on the live server - www.bairdswindows.co.uk.

Comment: culprit is folder name "icons"

Answer (score 1):

Fasthosts, my host company, don't allow a sub-directory called "icons" on their shared Unix/Linux servers.  Oh, and yes, they didn't bother telling anyone. Yay Fasthosts!  :|

NJ